# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The input data is not a complete block

Tags: c#, .net

Не могу понять, с чем связана данная ошибка в Dispose.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The input
> data is not a complete block.) --->
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The input data is
> not a complete block.    at
> Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoDecryptor.UncheckedTransformFinalBlock(Byte[]
> inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)    at
> Internal.Cryptography.UniversalCryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[]
> inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()    at
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

При этом при повторном запуске данная ошибка не возникает.

Comment: Думаю не успевает подгрузиться. И происходит вызов метода. Думаю дать немного времени на загрузку и будет всё ок. Во второй раз машина уже кешировала частично тяжелые библиотеки и проблем не возникают

Comment: пример кода? mcve? работает на одной машине и не работает на другой? как-то мало подробностей.

Comment: Вариант 1 - Если есть стрим Stream c данными -  в конце работы делайте Flush перед Close. Вариант 2 -  у каждого алгоритма есть BlockSize. В некоторых случаях нужно дополнять блок нулями или делать padding до размера кратного BlockSize. Не уверен что [2] это верное решение, поскольку может испортится шифрование, нужно чётко знать какой это шифр, и проверить на живом примере.